# Insert into Google Calendar in Wix

Tags: insert, calendar, google-calendar-api, velo

I am trying to  build a Google Calendar in Wix. I want to insert event via form.
- I cannot import external js.
or 
- I cannot post insert code to googleApi

```
import {fetch} from 'wix-fetch';

$w.onReady(function name  () { 
var start = "2018-11-01T10:00:00";
var end   = "2018-11-01T12:00:00";
 sendWithService("0","namesurname", "location", start, end, "note") 
})

//sendGrid.js
export function sendWithService(id,adisoyadi, lokasyon, start, end, not) {
const url = "https://api.sendgrid.com/api/mail.send.json";

const headers = {
"apiKey": apiKey,
"clientId": id,
"scope": 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar',
"discoveryDocs": ['https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/drive/v3/rest']
};


 const data = 'id :' +id "+ ',Description:' + adisoyadi + ', Location:'+lokasyon+' ,Start: ' + start +',End: ' + end+'}';
   //DateTime: "2015-05-28T09:00:00-07:00",
    const request = {
"method": "post", 
"headers": headers, 
"body": data
   };


   return fetch(url, request)
        .then(response => response.json());
      }
```

Comment: Can you add any details like: code used, error problem encountered? [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Show the community what you have tried.

Answer (score 1):

Hay Gorkem,

Your code is a page code, that is running on the browser. As such, it is subject to a browser security policy which prevents cross-domain calls.

You should do the fetch call from a wix code backend module, then import that module from the page code and call it. That will solve the cross-domain issue.

Comment: Thank you very much.. I will try. 
Just have a basic question? I cannot import backend js or jsw files in normal pages.. Also is this code **good / right**??